# Как создать счетчик

Tags: javascript

Нужно через каждые 20сек прибавлять число, к находящим в обрамлении DIV.

```
<div id="cell">10</div>
```

Как это сделать подскажите?

Comment: @big-vl, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: как считать время сколько прошло я так понимаю через if сравнивать я java не очень знаю но php более менее вот и возникают вопросы

Comment: java тут не причем, зачем через if, вам нужен setTimeOut, сам счетчик меняйте так: document.getElementById('cell').innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById('cell').innerHTML)+10;

Answer (score 3):

Напишите функцию, которая увеличивает таймер один раз, а потом передайте её в качестве параметра в метод `setInterval`.

Для наглядности счётчик в примере обновляется раз в две секунды.

```js
var updateTimer = function() {
  var cell = document.getElementById('cell');
  var count = Number(cell.innerHTML);

  cell.innerHTML = count += 1;
};

setInterval(updateTimer, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="cell">10</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval('NewCell()', 1000);
function NewCell() {
document.getElementById('cell').innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById('cell').innerHTML)+10;
}
```

Comment: Не делайте так больше с `setInterval`. Можно просто писать:

    setInterval(function(){
        ...
    },1000)

Comment: Можно, не делать? Почему? По мне, удобнее создать функцию, для наглядности.

Comment: Потому что передача строки в первый параметр setInterval/setTimeout эквивалентно eval()

Comment: а как лучше останавливать счетчик?

Comment: мне кажется что avengerweb прав так как я смогу потом сделать setInterval('NewCell()', 0);

Comment: avengerweb не прав, не делайте в кавычках.

останавливать:

    clearInterval(id)

id это то что возвращает функция setInterval()